# Making 2, back to back, consecutive updates to mongo

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm having some trouble to make 2 consecutive updates to my model. This is my small, general, update handler:

```
let updateHandler = function(prop, data, req, res, done) {
    Ingredient.update({ name: req.body.ingredientName }, {
        [prop]: data
    }, function(err, raw) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            res.send('/error');
        } else {
            console.log(raw);
            if(done) res.send('/ingredients');
        }
    })
}
```

And these are my calls:

```
updateHandler('name', req.body.ingredientNewName, req, res, false);
updateHandler('price', parseFloat(req.body.ingredientNewPrice), req, res, true);
```

I know the updateHandler is a little strange, and you might be asking yourself: "why on earth would you be doing this?".But that's not the point of this question. I want to understand why this isn't working.

When I execute both of my updates, only the first update actually modifies the model. I get this back:

```
{ ok: 1, nModified: 1, n: 1 } 
{ ok: 1, nModified: 0, n: 0 }
```

So I know for a fact that both updates happen but the second 1 doesn't modify anything. What's even weirder is that if on the first update there is no modification to be made, the second update works and makes a modification:

```
{ ok: 1, nModified: 0, n: 1 }
{ ok: 1, nModified: 1, n: 1 }
```

I really want to understand what's going on in here. I have a feeling it might be an async issue in which case maybe I could get around this with a promise. But the updates are actually being executed, so maybe something with mongo/mongoose?

Comment: Can you use `$set` in the 2nd argument of your update statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Isn't it obvious?

The first call you make based on `name: req.body.ingredientName` , and what you do in first call you change name to `req.body.ingredientNewName`

All fine,

Now the second call again you do `name: req.body.ingredientName`, but it doesn't find anything because name has been changed to `req.body.ingredientNewName` by your first query, so it doesn't find and doesn't change anything.

You do need a better structure and maybe pass the query `{ name: req.body.ingredientName }` through the function and first time you pass { name: req.body.ingredientName }, next time you pass { name: req.body.req.body.ingredientNewName }

That would be quick solution imo.